# Continue Execution after step fails in JBehave scenario

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I am using Selenium Webdriver with JBehave. My Jbehave Story contains few scenarios with some repetitive steps as shown in the below steps and I have created a common function to execute them.

```
Scenario: 25. Validate Column from Database 
Given I open application URL 
And I login with username "username1" and password "password1"
Then I validate the "column1" from database
Then I validate the "column2" from database
Then I validate the "column3" from database
Then I Logout of the Portal
```

This is my common function to validate the column from database

```
@Then("I validate the \"$column\" from database")
public void validateColumnFromDB(String column)
{
    if(column.equals("column1"))
       getColumnFromDB(propertiesConfiguration.getString("column1"));
    else if(column.equals("column2"))
       getColumnFromDB(propertiesConfiguration.getString("column2"));
    else if (column.equals("column3"))
       getColumnFromDB(propertiesConfiguration.getString("column3"));
}
```

I used Junit `ErrorCollector()` but after execution, JBehave says "All the tests passed" even though there are some failures and the `ErrorCollector()` collected them. Atleast JBehave should say some steps failed.

My question is I want to continue the execution in JBehave even after validaiton of any one of the column fails (ony one of Step mentioned in Scenario).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dont you need an assert in the `validateColumnFromDB` to check if value was retrieved successfully or not or this is done in `getColumnFromDB(..)`

Comment: Yep Assertions done in `getColumnFromDB()`

Comment: show your Embedder configuration.
do you use jbehave-junit-runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do cheking all of columns in a single step, in this way:

```
Scenario: 25. Validate Column from Database 

Given I open application URL 
Then I validate the following columns: "column1,column2,column3" from database
```

---

```
@Then("I validate the following columns: \"$columns\" from database")
public void then_i_walidate_columns_from_databale( List<String> columns){
    String columnsWithError = "";
    boolean validationResult = true;
    for( String column : columns){
        boolean validationResultOfCurrentColumn = ( null != getColumnFromDB(column));
        validationResult &= validationResultOfCurrentColumn;
        if( ! validationResultOfCurrentColumn ){
            columnsWithError += column + " ";
        }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue("The following columns don't pass the validation: " + columnsWithError, validationResult);
}
```

Comment: Well I have given only one example. But my basic question is I want to continue the execution even if one of the step fails. There might be a situation where steps might be independent to each other but flow doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you throwing an exception in a JBehave step when an error occurs? JBehave relies on knowing there is an error by your thrown exception. I'm wondering whether the ErrorCollector is consuming your thrown exceptions therefore your errors are not reaching JBehave, hence JBehave thinks there are no errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right I am using error collector. But, I want to print that error on the output.html whenever any error encounters. Is there anyway doing so?

Comment: JBehave is intended to stop executing a scenario at the step that causes a failure. It seems you want JBehave to execute all the steps and if multiple steps fail then report the failure for each step. If so then that is not how JBehave is expected to be used. Let it fail at the first step that can cause a failure.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the story runners are configured to **fail-fast**, i.e. the execution will stop at first failed story (but will complete execution of the all the scenarios in the story first). To allow the generation of a complete stories view (reporting how many stories failed), the runners need to be enabled to run stories with **ignoreFailureInStories** flag set to **true**.

Source: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/running-stories.html